# Android SearchView as Autocomplete?

Tags: android, xml, autocomplete, searchview

I am using a SearchView. I want to use AutoComplete feature on the searchView but i can't get the result from dropdown. I don't want to use AutoCompleteTextView.
Can you help me please

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SearchView search;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search);
        String data[]={"Emmanuel", "Olayemi", "Henrry", "Mark", "Steve", "Ayomide", "David", "Anthony", "Adekola", "Adenuga"};
        SearchView.SearchAutoComplete searchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) search.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, data);
        searchAutoComplete.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }
}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: searchautocomplete.tunisia.com.searchautocomplete, PID: 15125
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getCursor()' on a null object reference
>           at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.launchSuggestion(SearchView.java:1476)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.onItemClicked(SearchView.java:1389)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.SearchView$8.onItemClick(SearchView.java:1414)
>           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.performCompletion(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1017)
>           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.access$500(AutoCompleteTextView.java:96)
>           at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$DropDownItemClickListener.onItemClick(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1313)
>           at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:318)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1192)
>           at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3169)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:874)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:198)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6729)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text, in the question itself.

Comment: It's revised, thanks @MikeM.